# C# array sorting by %

Tags: c#

I have array with letters, like this:

```
10%  A
20%  A
30%  A
40%  B
50%  B
60%  B
70%  B
80%  C
90%  C
100% D
```

I need code to give me result like this:

```
A 10%-30%
B 40%-70$
C 80%-90%
D 100%-100%
```

Comment: Try something then comeback.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your attempt at solving the problem so we can point out where the problem is.

Comment: The way I tend to solve these sorts of problems is by imagining how I would do it myself (using physical cards or something)... thus my question to you would be: how would you do it manually?

Comment: What if you don't have `20% A`.  Would `A 10%-30%` still be valid?

Comment: No, certain letter can only be in the order and once appears no longer be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is sorted like that, this should work for you:

```
 var result =  values.GroupBy(x => x.Last())
                .Select(
                    x =>
                        string.Format("{0} {1} - {2}", x.Key.ToString(), 
                            x.First().Split()[0],
                            x.Last().Split()[0]));
```

Comment: I'll test. The above is a simplified example. In the field I have 100 entries, the resolution of the record is 1%. I have 4 letters (ABCD) set is sequential repetition. When come next letter, the former can no longer be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, topic starter was mean something like this:

```
static void Main() {
  var array = new [] { "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D" };
  var result = new Collection < string > ();

  //as u call it "resolution":
  const int resolution = 10;

  var currentSymbol = array[0];
  var startIndex = 1;

  for (var index = 0; index < array.Length; index++) {
    if (currentSymbol != array[index]) {
      result.Add(currentSymbol + " " + startIndex * resolution + "%-" + index * resolution);
      currentSymbol = array[index];
      startIndex = index + 1;
    }
    if (index + 1 == array.Length) {
      result.Add(currentSymbol + " " + startIndex * resolution + "%-" + (index + 1) * resolution);
      currentSymbol = array[index];
      startIndex = index + 1;
    }
  }

  foreach(var a in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```